# Нейроные сети для роботов

Tags: нейронные-сети

Знания радиотехники есть, программирования тоже.
Собрав очередного робота на колесиках ради забавы, задумался, что хотел бы сделать его умней, а не просто программировать статические реакции на события.

Подскажите, с чего бы начать, чтоб с самых азов? И по меньше математических формул, и по больше кода вместо них, так будет менее абстрактно.

Язык программирования не важен

Answer (score 1):

Помню читал вот этот цикл переводов с хабра http://habrahabr.ru/company/paysto/blog/244723/

Язык JS, но без математики все равно не обойтись, хотя она не слишком сложная.